# Duplicate timer entries in WEBLOGIC_TIMERS

Tags: timer, ejb, weblogic-10.x

I am working with a WebLogic 10.3.5 clustered environment.
My application includes an EJB timer, for which I implemented support as in the following  [example](http://shaoxiongyang.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-to-use-ejb-3-timer-in-weblogic-10.html). 
The timer is created for a single shot with a definite timeout, then created again when it's finished its job. In other words:

- create timer with (say) 5 minutes timeout
- the timer fires and starts its job
- the job ends and a new timer is created with the same period

As far as I know one-shot timers are automatically canceled by the application server when they have been fired.

I am dealing with a very serious problem because now I have a huge number of timer instances.
In the WEBLOGIC_TIMERS table I find a lot of entries instead of just one. All of them have a different START_TIME value and INTERVAL = -1.

This is a production environment, so I have little or no access to it. Weblogic nodes have been restarted but nothing has changed.

How can I solve this ? Can I just delete the rows from WEBLOGIC_TIMERS ?

Comment: Some more info about this strange behaviour. Asking the timer instance about its next timeout and remaining time (methods getNextTimeout() and getTimeRemaining() in javax.ejb.Timer) I get, respectively, a date in the past and about 24 hours. The DBMS is on a different server than the Weblogic cluster, so I asked someone to check for differences in system dates. The Oracle server is some minutes earlier than the weblogic servers. Could this explain ? And how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turned out that even small differences in system dates between the clustered weblogic servers and the dbms servers can cause the problem I described.
After having them synchronized by the sysadmins, the problem disappeared.